# How to list up all tables after a authority of a ContentProvider in android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

As my question in title. I want to show all tables that exist after a authority of a ContentProvider.

For example: content://my_authority_path/

There are URIs like:

```
content://my_authority_path/Keys/

content://my_authority_path/Passwords/
```

However, I don't know these URIs but only Authority. So how to know how many URIs there are after the Authority?
I have done search via Google but no result up to now. I hope that I can see some code as example.

Your comments are appreciated

Comment: what tables do you mean? remember that ContentProvider is general purpose interface and doesn't have to use any sql database

Comment: My question was not clear. I have updated more content. Can you read it again and give me your opinion?

Comment: ContentProvider doesn't advertise its path structure,  it can be anything,  its up to ContentProvider designer but its a good practice to expose its Uris in some kind of class/interface

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? I am using Drozer with this command:
run scanner.provider.finduris -a package_name
It yields Uris that are accessible or not.

content://com.mwr.example.sieve.DBContentProvider/Keys/
content://com.mwr.example.sieve.DBContentProvider/Passwords
content://com.mwr.example.sieve.DBContentProvider/Passwords/


I am wondering why Drozer can do it? If possible, I want to do it programmatically

Comment: sorry i have no idea what Drozer is...